# When to use a type class, when to use a type

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I was revisiting a piece of code I wrote to do combinatorial search a few months ago, and noticed that there was an alternative, simpler way to do something that I'd previously achieved with a type class.

Specifically, I previously had a type class for the type of *search problems*, which have an states of type `s`, actions (operations on states) of type `a`, an initial state, a way of getting a list of (action,state) pairs and a way of testing whether a state is a solution or not:

```
class Problem p s a where
    initial   :: p s a -> s
    successor :: p s a -> s -> [(a,s)]
    goaltest  :: p s a -> s -> Bool
```

This is somewhat unsatisfactory, as it requires the MultiParameterTypeClass extension, and generally needs FlexibleInstances and possibly TypeSynonymInstances when you want to make instances of this class. It also clutters up your function signatures, e.g.

```
pathToSolution :: Problem p => p s a -> [(a,s)]
```

I noticed today that I can get rid of the class entirely, and use a type instead, along the following lines

```
data Problem s a {
    initial   :: s,
    successor :: s -> [(a,s)],
    goaltest  :: s -> Bool
}
```

This doesn't require any extensions, the function signatures look nicer:

```
pathToSolution :: Problem s a -> [(a,s)]
```

and, most importantly, I found that after refactoring my code to use this abstraction instead of a type class, I was left with 15-20% fewer lines than I had previously.

The biggest win was in code that created abstractions using the type class - previously I had to create new data structures that wrapped the old ones in a complicated way, and then make them into instances of the `Problem` class (which required more language extensions) - lots of lines of code to do something relatively simple. After the refactor, I just had a couple of functions that did exactly what I wanted to.

I'm now looking through the rest of the code, trying to spot instances where I can replace type classes with types, and make more wins.

My question is: in what situation does will this refactoring **not** work? In what cases is it actually just better to use a type class rather than a data type, and how can you recognise those situations ahead of time, so you don't have to go through a costly refactoring?

Comment: To answer your parting questions - use a type class when you already have types. But, if what you want is really a "parametrized algorithm", consider a record-of-functions (your second design) rather than a class (your first design). Presumably to instantiate the Problem class you had to invent some rather artificial types - this is an indication that the design could be improved with a record-of-functions.

Comment: ...and when you do _have_ to use a class, you can replace horrid multi parameter type classes with lovely type families, explaining to the compiler how to calculate the other types rather than telling it there's a relationship between them. YMMV but I get far fewer errors and when I do add FlexibleContexts or FlexibleInstances, it's generally a sign I'm doing something interesting, rather than a sign I'm headed for a type class dead end and a re-design. (Great question, great answers: another SO win.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider a situation where both the type and class exist in the same program. The type can be an instance of the class, but that's rather trivial. More interesting is that you can write a function `fromProblemClass :: (CProblem p s a) => p s a -> TProblem s a`.

The refactoring you performed is roughly equivalent to manually inlining `fromProblemClass` everywhere you construct something used as a `CProblem` instance, and making every function that accepts a `CProblem` instance instead accept `TProblem`.

Since the only interesting parts of this refactoring are the definition of `TProblem` and the implementation of `fromProblemClass`, if you can write a similar type and function for any other class, you can likewise refactor it to eliminate the class entirely.

#### When does this work?

Think about the implementation of `fromProblemClass`. You'll essentially be partially applying each function of the class to a value of the instance type, and in the process eliminating any reference to the `p` parameter (which is what the type replaces).

Any situation where refactoring away a type class is straightforward is going to follow a similar pattern.

#### When is this counterproductive?

Imagine a simplified version of `Show`, with only the `show` function defined. This permits the same refactoring, applying `show` and replacing each instance with... a `String`. Clearly we've lost something here--namely, the ability to work with the original types and convert them to a `String` at various points. The value of `Show` is that it's defined on a wide variety of unrelated types.

As a rule of thumb, if there are many different functions specific to the types which are instances of the class, and these are often used in the same code as the class functions, delaying the conversion is useful. If there's a sharp dividing line between code that treats the types individually and code that uses the class, conversion functions might be more appropriate with a type class being a minor syntactic convenience. If the types are used almost exclusively through the class functions, the type class is probably completely superfluous.

#### When is this impossible?

Incidentally, the refactoring here is similar to the difference between a class and interface in OO languages; similarly, the type classes where this refactoring is impossible are those which can't be expressed directly *at all* in many OO languages.

More to the point, some examples of things you can't translate easily, if at all, in this manner:

- **The class's type parameter appearing only in covariant position**, such as the result type of a function or as a non-function value. Notable offenders here are `mempty` for `Monoid` and `return` for `Monad`.
- **The class's type parameter appearing more than once in a function's type** may not make this truly impossible but it complicates matters quite severely. Notable offenders here include `Eq`, `Ord`, and basically every numeric class.
- **Non-trivial use of higher kinds**, the specifics of which I'm not sure how to pin down, but `(>>=)` for `Monad` is a notable offender here. On the other hand, the `p` parameter in your class is not an issue.
- **Non-trivial use of multi-parameter type classes**, which I'm also uncertain how to pin down and gets horrendously complicated in practice anyway, being comparable to multiple dispatch in OO languages. Again, your class doesn't have an issue here.

Note that, given the above, this refactoring is not even *possible* for many of the standard type classes, and would be counterproductive for the few exceptions. This is not a coincidence. :]

#### What do you give up by applying this refactoring?

You give up the ability to distinguish between the original types. This sounds obvious, but it's potentially significant--if there are any situations where you *really* need to control which of the original class instance types was used, applying this refactoring loses some degree of type safety, which you can only recover by jumping through the same sort of hoops used elsewhere to ensure invariants at run-time.

Conversely, if there are situations where you really need to make the various instance types *interchangeable*--the convoluted wrapping you mentioned being a classic symptom of this--you gain a great deal by throwing away the original types. This is most often the case where you don't actually care much about the original data itself, but rather about how it lets you operate on other data; thus using records of functions directly is more natural than an extra layer of indirection.

As noted above, this relates closely to OOP and the type of problems it's best suited to, as well as representing the "other side" of the Expression Problem from what's typical in ML-style languages.

Comment: I believe that this refactoring is actually how GHC implements typeclasses.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: The class dictionaries behave more like distinct arguments to functions with a class context in their type, I think--not quite the same as bundling the dictionary with the value, or pre-applying the class functions outright.

Comment: "You give up the ability to distinguish between the original types." I think this can be regained easily enough by adding a "dummy" type parameter.  Instead of `data Problem s a = Problem s (s -> [(a,s)]) (s -> Bool)`, you would have `data Problem t s a = Problem s (s -> [(a,s)]) (s -> Bool)` (no mention of `t` on the right hand side), and functions with restrictive signatures like `fooProblem :: Foo -> Problem Foo T1 T2`.

Comment: @sacundim: Tagging with phantom types is one standard method of ensuring invariants at run-time, yes. The key point here is that you have the burden of ensuring that the tagging is correct--with truly distinct types, there's no possibility of mistaking one for the other.

Answer (score 5):

Your refactoring is closely related to this blog entry by Luke Palmer: ["Haskell Antipattern: Existential Typeclass"](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

I think we can prove that your refactoring will always work.  Why?  Intuitively, because if some type `Foo` contains enough information so that we can make it into an instance of your `Problem` class, we can always write a `Foo -> Problem` function that "projects" `Foo`'s relevant information into a `Problem` that contains exactly the information needed.

A bit more formally, we can sketch a proof that your refactoring always works.  First, to set the stage, the following code defines a translation of a `Problem` class instance into a concrete `CanonicalProblem` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Problem p s a where
    initial   :: p s a -> s
    successor :: p s a -> s -> [(a,s)]
    goaltest  :: p s a -> s -> Bool

data CanonicalProblem s a = CanonicalProblem {
    initial'   :: s,
    successor' :: s -> [(a,s)],
    goaltest'  :: s -> Bool
}

instance Problem CanonicalProblem s a where
    initial = initial'
    successor = successor'
    goaltest = goaltest'

canonicalize :: Problem p s a => p s a -> CanonicalProblem s a
canonicalize p = CanonicalProblem {
    initial' = initial p,
    successor' = successor p,
    goaltest' = goaltest p
}
```

Now we want to prove the following:

1. For any type `Foo` such that `instance Problem Foo s a`, it is possible to write a `canonicalizeFoo :: Foo s a -> CanonicalProblem s a` function that produces the same result as `canonicalize` when applied to any `Foo s a`.
2. It's possible to rewrite any function that uses the `Problem` class into an equivalent function that uses `CanonicalProblem` instead.  E.g., if you have `solve :: Problem p s a => p s a -> r`, you can write a `canonicalSolve :: CanonicalProblem s a -> r` that's equivalent to `solve . canonicalize`

I'll just sketch proofs.  In the case of (1), suppose you have a type `Foo` with this `Problem` instance:

```
instance Problem Foo s a where
    initial = initialFoo
    successor = successorFoo
    goaltest = goaltestFoo
```

Then given `x :: Foo s a` you can trivially prove the following by substitution:

```
-- definition of canonicalize
canonicalize :: Problem p s a => p s a -> CanonicalProblem s a
canonicalize x = CanonicalProblem {
                     initial' = initial x,
                     successor' = successor x,
                     goaltest' = goaltest x
                 }

-- specialize to the Problem instance for Foo s a
canonicalize :: Foo s a -> CanonicalProblem s a
canonicalize x = CanonicalProblem {
                     initial' = initialFoo x,
                     successor' = successorFoo x,
                     goaltest' = goaltestFoo x
                 }
```

And the latter can be used directly to define our desired `canonicalizeFoo` function.

In the case of (2), for any function `solve :: Problem p s a => p s a -> r` (or similar types that involve `Problem` constraints), and for any type `Foo` such that `instance Problem Foo s a`:

- Define `canonicalSolve :: CanonicalProblem s a -> r'` by taking the definition of `solve` and substituting all occurrences of `Problem` methods with their `CanonicalProblem` instance definitions.
- Prove that for any `x :: Foo s a`, `solve x` is equivalent to `canonicalSolve (canonicalize x)`.

Concrete proofs of (2) require concrete definitions of `solve` or related functions.  A general proof could go either of these two ways:

- Induction over all types that have `Problem p s a` constraints.
- Prove that all `Problem` functions can be written in terms of a small subset of the functions, prove that this subset has `CanonicalProblem` equivalents, and that the various ways of using them together preserves the equivalence.

Comment: Excellent. Can you explain under which conditions this plan for a proof is likely to fail? Can you formalise the key characteristics you used as general assumptions, and what sort of type classes would fail those conditions? OP: "My question is: in what situation does will this refactoring not work?"

Answer (score 1):

If you are from OOP backaground. You can think of typeclasses as interfaces in java. They are generally used when you want to provide same interface to different data types, generally involving data type specific implementations for each.

In your case there is no use of using a typeclass, it will only over complicate your code. 
for more informaction you can always refer to haskellwiki for better understanding.
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OOP_vs_type_classes

The general rule of thumb is: If you are doubtful whether you need type classes or not, then you probably don't need them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however my problem isn't with what a type class *is*, but with what rules of thumb there are to tell when you should be using one. The rule "if you're not sure if you need it, you probably don't" is good, but it's quite vague. Are there more hard-and-fast rules? In my example, the `p` in the class definition always appears at the far left of the type signature, which hints that the type class isn't necessary (Aside: the comparison with Java isn't helpful - in Java, you *would* use either an abstract class or an interface for this problem.)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: The better contrast here is class inheritance (abstract or not) vs. interfaces which couldn't be made into an abstract class (for whatever reason). The comparison is valid, but more subtle than it sounds.