# What are the common uses of type classes?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm going through type classes using [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) resource, I've come up with two uses:

a) Enabling functions to take different types without having to redefine the function interface:

```
class MyClass a where   
  myFunc :: a -> Bool

instance MyClass Int where
  myFunc 1 = False
  myFunc x = intFunction x

instance MyClass String where 
  myFunc "hello" = False
  myFunc y = stringFunction

intFunction :: a -> Bool
intFunction i
   | i > 100 = True
   | otherwise = False

stringFunction :: a -> Bool
stringFunction s 
   | length s > 10  = False
   | otherwise = True
```

b) Importing functionality into polymorphic functions:

```
class Operator a b where
  (^&) :: a -> b -> Bool

instance Operator a b where
  "hello" ^& 0   = True
  x ^& y = False

exampleFunc :: (Operator a b) => a -> b -> Bool
exampleFunc e1 e2 = e1 ^& e2
```

Questions:

1) What are the other uses of type classes in Haskell?

2) How are type classes generally used in large programs?

**N.B Apologies if this is a very broad question, I'm just trying to get a feel as to how I can structure my programs around type classes**

Comment: Related: [*When to use a type class, when to use a type*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12286315/2751851) (though it is more about what are the *good* uses of type classes, I suspect you can find at least some of your answer if you read between the lines).

Comment: @duplode should I delete this question? It's got quite a few close flags

Comment: Well, it is a broad question indeed, and it might be difficult to give it a comprehensive or conclusive answer (there are many ways to use classes to structure programs and libraries, and not everyone likes all of them). I considered closing your question as a duplicate of the one I linked to, but that might be a bit of a stretch. I wonder if there is a narrower question lying inside it that could net you an useful answer... So I would leave it here at least for a little longer, to see if we can e.g. narrow it down a bit or find a good duplicate -- @everyone: suggestions welcome!